# Reading in values from another excel file using XLRD

Tags: python, xlrd

I have two excel files that I have read into Python using xlrd. The first column for each of the excel files are different, but some numbers are the same. I would like to call each row from an excel file that matches the column values from another excel file. The goal is to be able to plot these values using Matplotlib.

For simplicity, my first excel file is my master file. The second excel file needs to correlate with this one.

```
 Excel file 1 (master_file):
      Distance    Temperature     Pressure
      5           57              1
      6           58              2
      8           55              1
      10          58              1
      37          65              1

 Excel file 2 (secondary_file):
      Distance    Temperature     Pressure
      5           57              1
      6           56              1
      7           58              2
      8           55              1
      10          58              1
      37          65              1
```

So if the value in Distance for secondary_file = the value in Distance for the master_file, I would like to return that output so I can plot it. I am plotting both of these files together in one plot, but only the values that correlate with the master_file.

I would like the output to be:

```
 distance = [5, 6, 8, 10, 37]
 master_file_T = [57, 58, 55, 58, 65]
 secondary_file_T= [57,56, 55, 58, 65]

 plt. plot (distance, master_file_T)
 plt. plot (distance, secondary_file_T)
```

Distance 7 for the secondary file is now excluded from my plots since there is not a correlating distance for 7 in the master_file. I have about 100 rows to go through so I am assuming a for loop of some sort is the way to go? I am very new to Python so any help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DataFrame.isin()`

```
master_file  = pd.DataFrame()
master_file['Distance']= [5, 6, 8, 10, 37]
master_file['Temperature'] = [57, 58, 55, 58, 65]
master_file['Pressure'] = [1,2,1,1,1]

secondary_file = pd.DataFrame()
secondary_file['Distance'] = [5, 6, 7,8, 10, 37]
secondary_file['Temperature']= [57,56, 58,55, 58, 65]
secondary_file['Pressure'] = [1,1,2,1,1,1]
```

```
distance = master_file.Distance.tolist()
master_file_T = master_file.Temperature.tolist()
secondary_file_T = secondary_file[secondary_file.Distance.isin(master_file.Distance)].Temperature.tolist()

print(distance,master_file_T,secondary_file_T)
```

```
[5, 6, 8, 10, 37]  
[57, 58, 55, 58, 65]  
[57, 56, 55, 58, 65]
```